# Is there a way to force thumbnail generation via a script

Tags: thumbnails, pcmanfm

I am currently using PCManFM, but I believe that other file managers are the same. When I open up the directory, large files, that are over the specified size limit are not shown as thumbnails, but only as the type-icons. I work on the directory of many large sized PNG files, and what I've noticed, when I open one of them with Gimp, it does something and from then on this file is shown with the thumbnail unless I rename/move that file.

It would be very useful to be able to "nudge" the specific directory to generate the thumbnails regardless of the file size. Is there a way to script whatever it is that Gimp is doing, perhaps using "imagemagic" to generate the thumbnails and place them in the correct place somewhere.

Comment: I think you can write a script that checks the sizes and then resizes those files above the limit to a standard defined size, even if that is by using width and height.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider Yeah, i have written a script in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the thumbnail size limit to 0. Setting the size to 0 makes it ignore size.